error occurring while to create Laravel app
I am creating the Laravel app but while creating the app but I get this error:
Failed to download sebastian/environment from dist: The "https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/environment/legacy.zip/4eb3a442574d0e9d141aab209cd4aaf25701b09a" file could not be written to D:\apps\laravel\example-app/vendor/composer/tmp-be65f204e24604697aa4cddc7602b03b.zip: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

How I can resolve this error?

Which command you are using to install Laravel? Which PHP & Laravel version you are using/trying to install?

"composers create-project laravel/laravel example-app" this command I am using Composer version 2.7.6
PHP version 8.2.20

Laravel version 11

It is composer not composers.Try with this composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app.
